# jquery banner slider problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working through a Dreamweaver video tutorial and I've got stuck on this one part. The instructor is showing how to add a banner slider that has 4 images. The images simply fade out and the next one displays. There is no navigation on the images and there is also a feature that shows a paragraph of text that slides down for a few seconds and then back up as each image is displayed.

My problem is that he charges money for the js files he uses. I don't have the money to pay for it. He says you can simply search google for banner slider and find one but I've spent hours doing this and I can't find a free one that uses jquery and that I can understand how to use. I was wondering if anyone could point me to a free jquery banner slider that has good instructions for someone like me who has no experience with it.

The images need to be 900px by 300px. I'm comfortable with html and css but clueless when it comes to javascript. Thanks in advance.

The video I'm talking about is at [this link](https://youtu.be/TBz4DIgEq-8?list=PLwglS51ddbZEPeURdjLDqFZ4saPGd5EiL) and you can see an example of the banner as soon as the video starts.

Edit: This is information I'm adding to respond to the answer given by psobko.

I'm editing this again because I've got the slider to work. Now I just need to figure out how to get a text/caption to come up. If someone could instruct me the code to use in my css and html to get the captions to slide in and then slide out that would be great. [This link](http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html) shows examples of the caption effect but I'm not sure how to code it. Thank you.

Second Edit:

```
<div><img u="image" src="../images/banner/b1.jpg" />
<div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute;
top: 30px; left: 30px; width: 50px;height: 50px;">
Hello World</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh ok the effect you're looking for is called "carousel" you can do a web search (combined with the word jQuery) and it will turn up ~700k results. The top result is [this](http://www.jssor.com/) which seems to be ok and 100% free. Most common effects/layouts/etc which you see on the internet are free and open source (you can literally view the source of anything thanks with your browser). Don't pay for something unless you need special support, that you can't get from places like this, or you want to support the author and they don't have a donate button.

Comment: Please see my edit in my original post. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: can you post up an example of how you're using the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2v97k18/ Thanks so much for looking into this for me. I obviously have some work to do on the topnav links.

Comment: I think the caption I'm wanting to use on all slides is the _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] see this link: https://github.com/jssor/slider/blob/master/examples-jquery/slider-with-caption.source.html

Comment: Please see second edit in original post. Is that the correct html? If so I just need to know what js to add to my head section.